# alignment is not getting proper in different resolution

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

i am working on visual studio 2010.
i created my master form windows state is `Maximized`
my system resolution is  `1366X768` ,,in one button click i am calling 5 forms together into my master form.. but in my system everything getting correct..

[image]

but i installed the same application in my client system,,that system resolution is `1024X768`
but here my alignment is not getting proper..now my image is getting like this:[image]

so how i can fit my windows form application in all resolution,,if any one know please help me to find out

Comment: We need to see "bad image" as well. Change resolution on your computer, or just reduce the size of the window to approximately  1024x768.

Comment: sir i changed my screen resolution  1024x768.,now i am getting the screen like this:update image in my question

Comment: Is it necessary to have everything on one screen? Could the elements of the GUI be rearranged? What if "released vehicles" table stands below "retrieval alert"?

Comment: sir i need everything on one screen at any resolution..so what i have to do??

Comment: This question should be moved to [ux.se]. That site is specialized for exactly this types of problems.

Comment: Also, please answer other questions. Could "released vehicles" table stand below "retrieval alert" table?

Comment: no sir,,i have to keep released vehicles" table next to retrieval alert table..

Comment: @Dialecticus: Layouting issues such as this are technical and a better fit here than on UX. UX is mostly conceptual.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options:

1) Follow Microsoft's instruction on implementing auotscaling for Windows forms applications. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605(v=vs.110).aspx)

2) Write your own code to scale the form based on resolution.

============================

Other factors to keep in mind.

- If you app is translatable that can affect scaling
- A user changing the Windows default font size can have the same affect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: By writing your own code I mean handling the resize event on the main form. Say you always want the left-most panel to be 20% of the size of the main panel. When the resize event is call you could say formLeft.Width = formMain.Width * .20. You would also have to resize all the child controls.

Comment: See this article for more of an explanation: [How to auto-resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248637/how-to-auto-resize-and-adjust-form-controls-with-change-in-resolution)