# how to do Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms in c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Created a windows forms in 100 DPI.
now i change the DPI and Screen resolution.
but form cannot resize based on the current resolution.Is there any way to do automatic scaling in windows forms.

Comment: You can use Devexpress controls instead and lock your positioning, its not free though.

Comment: This question is very broad, there so many different ways to go about it, from creating your own scale to simply using a different layout style like the accepted answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248637/how-to-auto-resize-and-adjust-form-controls-with-change-in-resolution

Comment: Have a look into Form.AutoScaleMode

Comment: What kind of auto scale in winforms are you looking for?? In my case I use a custom function added to the forms SizeChanged Event.. And make the calculations myself.. it's a lot easier then looking for one..

Comment: Any thing is fine.Just need to solve.