# Make forms fit to every size of screen

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, user-controls

I finished developing my first windows forms application in c#, but when running it on a different Computer with a different screen size, the controls are not where they are supposed to be.

I used

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

to maximize the screen, but when doing this the form is just extended at the bottom and the controls stay at the same position.

Comment: Yea the controls would never move unless they are docked somewhere, which they are not in your case probably. A workaround is to set `autoscalemode` to `None` , `StartPosition` to `CentreScreen` and `MinimizeBox ` to `false`. 
If you cant do the above for some reason you need to use dock and anchor controls from each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto resize and adjust Form controls with change in resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248637/how-to-auto-resize-and-adjust-form-controls-with-change-in-resolution)

Comment: take a look at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735174/how-to-write-winforms-code-that-auto-scales-to-system-font-and-dpi-settings) it gives a good discussion auto scaling and winforms

Comment: In WinForms using panels and the dock property is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI For responsive design 
1st create below class

```
 public class Resolution
    {
        float heightRatio = new float();
        float widthRatio = new float();
        int standardHeight, standardWidth;
        public void ResizeForm(Form objForm, int DesignerHeight, int DesignerWidth)
        {
            standardHeight = DesignerHeight;
            standardWidth = DesignerWidth;
            int presentHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;//.Bounds.Height;
            int presentWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
            heightRatio = (float)((float)presentHeight / (float)standardHeight);
            widthRatio = (float)((float)presentWidth / (float)standardWidth);
            objForm.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None;
            objForm.Scale(new SizeF(widthRatio, heightRatio));
            foreach (Control c in objForm.Controls)
            {
                if (c.HasChildren)
                {
                    ResizeControlStore(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    c.Font = new Font(c.Font.FontFamily, c.Font.Size * heightRatio, c.Font.Style, c.Font.Unit, ((byte)(0)));
                }
            }
            objForm.Font = new Font(objForm.Font.FontFamily, objForm.Font.Size * heightRatio, objForm.Font.Style, objForm.Font.Unit, ((byte)(0)));
        }

        private void ResizeControlStore(Control objCtl)
        {
            if (objCtl.HasChildren)
            {
                foreach (Control cChildren in objCtl.Controls)
                {
                    if (cChildren.HasChildren)
                    {
                        ResizeControlStore(cChildren);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cChildren.Font = new Font(cChildren.Font.FontFamily, cChildren.Font.Size * heightRatio, cChildren.Font.Style, cChildren.Font.Unit, ((byte)(0)));
                    }
                }
                objCtl.Font = new Font(objCtl.Font.FontFamily, objCtl.Font.Size * heightRatio, objCtl.Font.Style, objCtl.Font.Unit, ((byte)(0)));
            }
            else
            {
                objCtl.Font = new Font(objCtl.Font.FontFamily, objCtl.Font.Size * heightRatio, objCtl.Font.Style, objCtl.Font.Unit, ((byte)(0)));
            }
        }
    }
```

> then when ever yo add any form the add panel control to form and dock
>   it to form
>   below
>   **InitializeComponent();**

Write below code

```
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    int screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    int screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
    Resolution objFormResizer = new Resolution();
    objFormResizer.ResizeForm(this, screenHeight, screenWidth);
```

this will make form responsive as much as possible as well as create system default font as well

Comment: Thank you, I combined the answers and now it works :) But when I use this code, the font cell style of datagridview in my forms is changed.

Answer (score 4):

Use **anchor** and **dock** Property for the control you need.

**Dock** : The Dock property forces a control to stick to a certain edge of the parent form (or control) like glue.

For example :

If you have an Image Box and you set the dock to the bottom right, after you maximize your windows, the Image Box will stay on the bottom right.

You can also use "Fill" to your **Dock** Property to make the size also dynamic depends on the windows size.